# Is it possible to call someone and when no ones answer the next contact will be called?

Tags: java, android, android-phone-call

Is it possible to call someone and when no ones answer the next contact will be called?
I am tryin to code such an app, I read [Build a calling app](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged), but it do not understand even to make a normal call with a custom UI. I'm frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get phone call state the below piece of code will help you.

```
PhoneStateChangeListener pscl = new PhoneStateChangeListener();
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tm.listen(pscl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

After the state you can internally trigger next call if it is not answered .

for more phone state listener please view [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener)

The below code is an example for call a number by indent using normal way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

dont forget to add the permission to do the call

```
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it later.

Comment: I thing it doesn't work. There is no "not answered" state and I do not have the possibility to overwrite a call.